# Problems with variables in associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I would like to have default string as values of an associative array if a user didn't fill in the field. For example "not inserted". If a user fills in the field, a variable should take the value the user put. So I wrote this code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if (isset($_POST['name'])){
        $name =$_POST['name'];     
} else {
        $name = "not inserted";
}
if (isset($_POST['surname'])){
    $surname =$_POST['surname']; 
} else {
    $surname = "not inserted";
}
if (isset($_POST['job'])) { 
    $job = $_POST['job'];
} else {
   $job = "not inserted";
}
    $data = array('name'=>$name, 'surname'=>$surname, 'job'=>$job);
    print_r($data);
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">

<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
<input type="text" id="surname" name="surname"/>
<input type="text" id="job" name="job"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"/>

</form>
```

But if I don't fill in some field instead of "not inserted" string print_r shows me the following result:

```
Array ( [name] => [surname] => [job] => )
```

Please, can someone tell me where did I go wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Try: **if (isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name']!=""){$name =$_POST['name'];} else {$name = "not 
inserted";}**

Comment: [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) checks if a variable exists and its value is not `NULL`. When your form is submitted, `$_POST['name']` and the other values you check exist and are not `NULL`. They may be `''` (the empty string) and the functions [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) can help you to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blank inputs are still posted to a forms action page, even if they have no content. So if you were to `var_dump($_POST)` when leaving all your fields empty, you'd see something like this:

```
array (size=3)
  'name' => string '' (length=0)
  'surname' => string '' (length=0)
  'job' => string '' (length=0)
  ...
```

They *are* set (i.e. they exist) but are empty. You can check if there is a value in there using the `empty()` function like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
} else {
    $name = "not inserted";
}
if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
} else {
    $name = "not inserted";
}
if (!empty($_POST['job'])) {
    $name = $_POST['job'];
} else {
    $name = "not inserted";
}
```

Read more about how `empty` works [in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: OK, I UNDERSTAND now. Thank you for the solution, but moreover, thank you for the EXPLANATION. Now I got it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work the way you want it to.

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
<input type="text" id="surname" name="surname"/>
<input type="text" id="job" name="job"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"/>

</form>
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      if ($name == "") { $name = "not interested";}
      $surname = $_POST['surname'];
      if ($surname == "") { $surname = "not interested";}
      $job = $_POST['job'];
      if ($job == ""){$job = "not interested";}
      $data = array('name'=>$name, 'surname'=>$surname, 'job'=>$job);
      print_r($data);
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers and just to show another way to do this, you could use the ternary operator.Which kind of makes it neater, but that is a matter of taste.

```
<?php
$name = ! empty($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "not inserted";
$surname = ! empty($_POST['surname']) ? $_POST['surname'] : "not inserted";
$job = ! empty($_POST['job']) ? $_POST['job'] : "not inserted";

$data = array('name' => $name, 'surname' => $surname, 'job' => $job);
?>
```

As an aside...You could refactor it a bit further to make a function you can reuse. Typically the function would go into another file that you would include with your files that use the forms... and on and on.

```
<?php

$name = read_post_value('name', 'not inserted');
$surname = read_post_value('surname', 'not inserted');
$job = read_post_value('job', 'not inserted');

$data = array('name' => $name, 'surname' => $surname, 'job' => $job);

var_dump($_POST); // Debug - Show $_POST contents
var_dump($data);  // Debug - Show $data contents

/**
 * Read a post entry.
 * Assign a default value if it is empty or does not exist
 */
function read_post_value($name, $default_text = '') {
    return ! empty($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : $default_text;
}
?>
```