# What is the best way to write the code that sum the values of checkbox choices

Tags: php, forms

I would like to have a form that enables a user to choose the vehicles. The user should get the total price of his choice. I wrote this little script, and it works properly. I am just curious is there a better way to do it. For example, there are a lot of IFs in foreach loop. What if I have, for instance, 100 checkboxes. Should I automate that in a way that for every new type of vehicle the script should make new IF statement? That sounds awkward. Is there a way to put a number of prices directly in checkbox form or something? However, what would be the best way to do such a thing. Thanx.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $automobils=$_POST['auto'];
    $set= array();

    echo "You ordered: " ;
    foreach ($automobils as $model){
        if ($model == "chevrolet"){
            $set[]=20000;
        }
        if ($model == "reno"){
            $set[]=15000;
        }
        if ($model == "punto"){
            $set[]=10000;
        }
        echo "<i>$model </i>";
    }
    $sum = array_sum($set);
    echo "</br> Whole price is $sum $";
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="auto[]" value="chevrolet"/> Chevrolet</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="auto[]" value="reno"/> Reno</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="auto[]" value="punto"/> Punto</br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: Using a Database would serve you well in this situation.

Comment: ^^^^^ is your solution, now you just need to learn another 100 things

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49300164/problems-with-variables-in-associative-arrays what about that one? or should we just assume it's been solved?

Comment: What does ^^^^ mean?

Comment: Means read the comment above

Comment: Funk Forty Niner, Who you ask?

Comment: And he's asking that if you found an answer, please mark it 'answered' so that person can get credit and your question doesn't show up on the lists as unanswered.

Comment: I would like to do that, gladly, but I can not find how. I am new here. Please, how to do that?

Comment: OK, Yes.Found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well without adding a database and a whole another level of fun programming.
You can do this with an explode command (And really shrinks your foreach as well)

on the input value

```
 value="chevrolet"
```

Change to something like

```
 value="chevrolet;20000"
```

then in your foreach loop

```
 foreach ($automobils as $model){
      $eachmodel = explode(";",$model);
      $set[] = $eachmodel[1];
 }
```

Comment: Except this means the price is editable by the user in the DOM.

Comment: Well as this looks more like a simple starter project, I don't think we need to worry too much. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd store your possible values, and their corresponding prices, in a database, rather than in your code. But here's a quick solution, involving an associative array acting as a map between each vehicle and its price.

```
$map = [
    'chevrolet' => 20000,
    'reno' => 15000,
    'punto' => 10000
];
if (!empty($_POST['auto']) {
    echo 'You ordered:<br />';
    $total = 0;
    foreach($_POST['auto'] as $model)
        if (array_key_exists($model, $map)) {
            echo ' - '.$model.'<br />';
            $total += $map[$model];
        }
    echo 'Total price: '.$total.'<br />';
}
```

Then, you just update the map as you add/change vehicles/prices etc.

Note it's key to store the allowed values/prices code-side (or in a DB) rather than in your form as the latter is editable via the DOM, so you'd need something server-side to validate it anyway.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to put number in checkbox. You can put it with value by using some special separator. 
For example

```
<input type="checkbox" name="auto[]" value="punto_20000"/> Punto</br>
```

Later you can use Explode string and can get value for selected.